# Connection timeout in JMeter does not work

Tags: jmeter

[image]

As shown in the above image, I have set a connection timeout of 20ms for the requests. However, I'm still getting sample times of over 20 (below image).

[image]

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that your `add obvervation15` is a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, HTTP Request Defaults will work only for the HTTP Request samplers, any other sampler types won't respect the timeout setting
2. If the  `add obvervation15` is a HTTP Request sampler - ensure that it's in the HTTP Request Defaults' [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) otherwise the timeouts won't be applied

Given above 2 conditions are met the timeouts will be respected:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the limitation of JMeter, because even when you set the connection limitation to 20ms, the query does not finish exactly at 20ms and goes beyond that time (in your example, the first query stops at 24ms and the third query stops at 68ms).